# How to add CSS styles to element via other CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, compass

I have a certain question about applying styles to an element through another CSS class. To be more specific, lets have a look at following. I have div:

```
<div class="main"></div>
```

with some styles:

```
.main { 
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  /* some other styles */
}
```

and I want to apply `.another` class to the div, but via its `.main` CSS.

```
.main {
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  .another
}

.another {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I assume that a preprocessor (SASS, Compass, etc.) is needed, but can someone advice if this is possible and what to keep in mind?

Thanks

Comment: You can have more than one class on an element so you could write `<div class="main another"></div>` Otherwise you'd need something like sass

Comment: Can I ask why? Surely it would require less to just type width:/height: in the .main class?

Comment: thanks for the answers, well basically I cannot change the markup of the HTML. I only can change the CSS.

Comment: If you want to create a new css class but to not add any new classes onto your markup, then `div.main {width: 50px;height:100px;}` is a different way to style the same element without any new classes in your markup, but it would also work if you have the `.main` css class twice in your css file. Both will work.

Comment: @Pete I guess thats what I search for!

Answer (score 0):

No preprocessor is needed, you can group classes with `.class.another`, that's the same thing that css preprocessors does.

You can just add multiple classes in html, like `<div class="main another and-other">...</div>`. In css, you can just group the selectors, the inline order doesn't matter, but it's recommended to use most used class (`main`) first, and add more specific classes lower. But the order from top to bottom matters, lower in file the selector is, more important it is.

I've created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4hzuah/) from your code, take a look. I've added background color so you see the difference, because width and height does not apply to inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign multiple class to that div. so you can write like this and can apply class.

```
<div class="main another"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two styles like:

```
.main.another {
  background: red;
  display: inline;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```